# Can't mount RAID5 via USB: File too large

Tags: usb, storage, raid

I have RAID 5 self-powered external array in here, and I can't mount it.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 36.4T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0  200M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0 36.4T  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 59.5G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0 41.8M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 59.4G  0 part /
```

FS is HFS+, so I've installed hfstools and tried this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sda2 /media/vault
mount: mount /dev/sda2 on /media/vault failed: File too large
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mount `36.4 terrabyte`. Wikipedia says to [mounting HFS+ partitions on Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#Linux):

> In 2009, these drivers were diagnosed to be corrupting HFS+ drives
>   with a capacity greater than 2 TB.[19] Consequently, Linux
>   distributions such as Debian and Ubuntu also stopped allowing mounting
>   of HFS+ drives or partitions greater than 2 TB. As of February 2011, work is in progress to lift this restriction. [[21]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus#cite_note-21)

Comment: What a sad life, so there's totally no way to use HFS+ in Linux..?

Comment: @holms Don't know, I use debian with its default file system ext4. But it seems there is some hope for HFS+. I have updated my answer. Quote: _"As of February 2011, work is in progress to lift this restriction."_ Follow note [21]

Comment: Okay there's seems to be Paragon ntfs/hfs+ for linux 9 product working just fine. Software costs 25£ and fine with paying this amount, as I'll be using this raid array a lot under under mac too not just for rpi

Comment: Is this because Raspbian is 32-bit? Will it work with a 64-bit Raspbian? I have a normal mdadm array that isn't mounting also and giving the same error. I don't know if it's HFS+.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was trying to mount my 64 TB array, and it didn't work with the same error. I thought the 2 TB limit has something to do with 32-bit, and it does. Here's the soluion:

```
Change your raspberry pi kernel to a 64-bit kernel
```

You can do this with Raspberry Pi 4, not with the older ones. To do this:

First, make sure you're using Debian Buster (version 10) or later by running this:

```
lsb_release -a
```

The output should be:

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

(if it's not buster, please stop... I can't guarantee the outcome. Find out how to upgrade to buster then come back).

Then update and upgrade your system to the latest of everything:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then make sure that you DO have the 64-bit kernel file:

```
ls /boot/kernel8.img
```

If this exists and doesn't give an error, you're probably good to go.

**WARNING**: This may fail and you may need to revert it. I'll give you an example on how this failed for me and I honestly don't know if there was another reason. But if it does fail, make sure you have a Linux system somewhere where you can edit the configuration file I'll be talking about without booting the system. Simply insert the SD card, and edit `config.txt` in the boot partition (which will be a drive on its own in Ubuntu and similar systems).

To switch to 64-bit:

1. edit the fail `/boot/config.txt`
2. find the section `[pi4]` in that file
3. if the section doesn't exist, add it at the end of the file (simply add `[pi4]` at the end of the file)
4. after adding that section, add under it `arm_64bit=1`
5. reboot
6. if it boots, run `uname -a`, and it should show you `aarch64` within the text of the result. This means you succeeded.

Now, **if it doesn't boot**. For me, it didn't boot the first time because I added the `arm_64bit=1` in the wrong section. Quite frankly I have no idea if this is the only reason. But I took my SSD (I don't use an SD card), plugged it into another computer, changed that, and then it booted. So, you gotta give it a shot.

**PS:** Not everything works out of the box on 64-bit. Kodi, Java and Wolfram Mathematica have problems (not impossible to fix, but needs work). Please investigate these on your own.

After this, mounting my array with mdadm worked.

Good luck!